# Computations of common isometry groups, $O(n)/O(n-1), SO(n)/SO(n-1), U(n)/U(n-1)$, etc?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

On wikipedia, some of the common isometry groups are given: $S^{n-1}\cong O(n)/O(n-1)$, $S^{n-1}\cong SO(n)/SO(n-1)$, etc.

Is there a reference where some/any of these groups are computed? I'm just curious to see how these homeomorphisms arise.

Comment: $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ act smoothly in the obvious way on $S^{n-1}$. The stabilizer of $e_1$ (the unit vector with 1 in the first coordinate) is isomorphic to $O(n-1)$ and $S0(n-1)$ respectively. If $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ a closed Lie subgroup, there is a unique way to give $G/H$ a manifold structure respecting the above action. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space