# Is de Sitter space $ dS_4 = SO(1,4)/SO(1,3)$?

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, mathematical-physics, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

A $D$-dimensional de Sitter spacetime $dS_D$ is a timelike hyperbola embedded in $(D+1)$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime $\mathfrak M_{D+1}$. The metric in the embedding space is

$$ ds^2 = (dX_0)^2 - \sum_{A=1}^D (dX_A)^2 \,.$$

With a radius $l\gt0$, $dS_D$ is defined by

$$ -\eta_{AB}X^AX^B = l^2 \,. $$

I would like to prove the popular claim that

$$ \boxed{ dS_D = \frac{O(1,D)}{O(1,D-1)} = \frac{SO(1,D)}{SO(1,D-1)} }\,.$$

Note that $O(1,D)$ is the Lorentz group which is a part of the isometry group of $\mathfrak M_{D+1}$ and $ O(1,D-1) \subset O(1,D) $ is the stabilizer of $dS_D$.

Alternatively, one can see that under a Wick rotation $X_0 \mapsto iX_0,\ dS_D \mapsto S^D \subset \mathbb R^{D+1}\,.$ So, *perhaps* an equivalent claim would be the following.

$$ \boxed{ S^D = \frac{O(D+1)}{O(D)} = \frac{SO(D+1)}{SO(D)} }\,.$$

A question requesting a proof of the above [has been made already](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/961143/404320), but no answers have been received so far.

Another example is the following. A $D$-dimensional anti de Sitter spacetime $AdS_D$ is embedded in a $(D+1)$-dimensional spacetime with a Lorentzian metric of index 2.

$$ ds^2 = (dX_0)^2 - \sum_{A=1}^{D-1} (dX_A)^2 + (dX_D)^2 \,.$$

With a radius $l\gt0$, $AdS_D$ is defined by

$$ \eta_{AB}X^AX^B = l^2 \,. $$

Now the claim is the following:

$$ \boxed { AdS_D = \frac{O(2,D-1)}{O(1,D-1)} = \frac{SO(2,D-1)}{SO(1,D-1)} }\,.$$

Note that each of the boxed claims are (loosely speaking) equivalent modulo various Wick rotations. I would appreciate even a sketch of proof for above claims.

Comment: "Wick rotation" does not actually prove the Lorentzian statement from the Euclidean statement; at best it suggests it as a conjecture.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, right. I was not claiming rigorous equivalence anyway. Nevertheless, do you have a proof for the original claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

(1) First prove that for every $v\in dS_D$ there exists $g\in O(1,D)$ such that $g(v)={\mathbf e}_1= (0,1,0,0,...0)$.

(2) Then check that the stabilizer of ${\mathbf e}_1$ in $O(1,D)$ is isomorphic to $O(1,D-1)$.

(3) Next, define a continuous (actually, smooth) map $O(1,D)\to dS_D$ sending $g\in O(1,D)$ to $g({\mathbf e}_1)$.

(4) Check that this map descends to a continuous (actually, smooth) injective map $f: O(1, D)/O(1,D-1)\to ds_D$ (using Part 2).

(5) Check (using Part 1) that  $f$ is surjective.

Thus, you have a bijective continuous map between two topological manifolds, which implies that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

(6) If you still care about the problem after the first 5 steps, show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism by appealing, for instance, to the Constant Rank Theorem.

Comment: Can you give a little more hints for step 2 please?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe: Let ${\mathbf e}_1^\perp$ be the Lorentzian orthogonal complement $H$ to the line spanned by ${\mathbf e}_1$. Compute the signature of $q$, which is the Lorentzian form restricted to that subspace. Verify that it is invariant under the stabilizer of ${\mathbf e}_1$ in $O(1,D)$. Thnk how to extend each element of $O(H, q)$ to an element of $O(1,D)$.